# Use a pattern to draw an image in HTML5/JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a project I'm currently working on that I cannot seem to Google a solution for. I have an HTML canvas that I'm using ctx.drawImage() to stack a couple images, the issue I'm having is I cannot figure out a way to draw an image specifically [this](http://i685.photobucket.com/albums/vv211/rickijilltrip/Alabama-A-psd-Free-Download-1265509127156.png), using a pattern like [this](http://www.voguefabricsstore.com/images/D/SparkleVinyl-Gold-700-2-01.jpg). Is there anyway this can be done easy, or would I need to attempt to generate the image server-side then push it to the client to draw?

The order of images I'm attempting to draw is as follows:

- Background Color
- A rounded mask
- The first linked image (this is the one that I want to draw with a pattern)

I'm trying to keep the first two layers visible, and just covering the non-transparent part of the third with the pattern file. All layers have the parts that need to be transparent set as transparent.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated** to meet additional conditions added to question since this answer was first posted:

You don't state if the rounded mask has filled or transparent center but the following assumes filled center:

- Draw letter image
- Change comp. mode to "`source-atop`" (see old answer below on how-to)
- Draw pattern. You now have the pattern in the shape of the letter.
- Change comp. mode to "`destination-over`"
- Draw mask, this will end up "behind" existing content
- Fill canvas with background color using same comp. mode.

**Old answer**

Sure, draw the first image, provided it has an alpha channel, to the canvas.

Then change composite mode to `source-atop` (`source-in` can also be used but it will remove existing content which doesn't end up under the new pixels):

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
```

Then draw the second image on top. To change back to the normal mode:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```